# What is the deal with THE most viewed question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Far and away*, the most popular question on this site is the [A-10 dark spot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2078/6886) one. I'm curious, does anyone have an explanation?

*nothing within 50k views

Comment: My answer is awesome! ;)

Answer (score 7):

Most questions with a huge number of views spent some time in the hot question list that gets displayed on all sites.  This question in particular got much wider exposure and wound up in aggregator sites, notably news.ycombinator.com (and iirc, the number one spot on that site for a time).  The well-above-normal exposure drove a huge number of page views.

Comment: Ummm... 130k views is still something of a something :/

Comment: Yep, that question [earned both the first _and second_ announcer badges](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) awarded on Aviation.

Answer (score 5):

The snake biting its tail:

[image]